# Send HTTP-PUT-Request takes no effect although status code is 200

Tags: java, json, http, http-headers, put

I want to sent a Http- PUT-Request which holds a JSON-Body, but I do not know how to define that body. I have tried out a lot by know, but always getting the same problem. Btw, I have already tested the put-request in postman, and it worked as it should, but I cannot realize this request in Java.

My latest try Looks like this:

```
String sURL = "http://localhost/Thingworx/Things/testAC/Properties/*";
HttpURLConnection urlConn;
URL mUrl = new URL(sURL);
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();

//query should be the body
String query = String.format("{\"datDate\":%s,\"txtFrom\": %s,\"txtTo\": %s,\"numFlightTimeDecimal\":%f,\"numSeatCapacity\":%d,\"numLoad\":%d,\"numDirt\":%f,\"numTotalFlightTime\":%f,\"numCummulatedDirt\":%f}", javaDate.toString(), txtFrom, txtTo, numFlightTimeDecimal, numSeatCapacity, numLoad, numDirt, numTotalFlightTime, numCumDirt);
urlConn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("appKey", "1042fdd2-8e85-4de1-9c92-d79ac24c1ffc");
urlConn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);

if (query != null) {
  urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(query.length()));
  urlConn.getOutputStream().write(query.getBytes("UTF8"));
 }

System.err.println(urlConn.getResponseCode());
```

The Response code says 200, which should be fine then. But the PUT-Request doesnt change any values on the server. The request does not show any effect.

Thank you in advance for any Kind help or advice!
Theresa

Comment: Is the receiving application a known one? Does it produce any logs one could check?

Comment: you can generate code in java from Postman and try to run that. Link: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/code_snippets

Comment: your length calculation will fail if the string contains non-ASCII characters...

Comment: If you are trying to compose a JSON document to put, you made some mistakes, All the string values are not quoted. You may want to use a library that serializes to JSON correctly.

Comment: Can't really tell anything without having a look at the server side code. If this gives you a 200, then it maybe fine, but the server side is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlConn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
```

Sets the request method to PUT.

```
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Enables output and sets the request method to POST. See the Javadoc. You need to do this first, not last.

NB Don't set the content-length. Java will do that for you.